how to use waitForUrl to wait for a url using playwright?
I am waiting for a url https://www.test.com/test/test I'm using this.page.waitForUrl("**test.com/test**) but that's giving me an error. Is that the right way to wait for that url?
The test fails there saying that it can't find the url. The regular expression is the wrong one even though it redirected to that url.

What error, specifically? Please share a [mcve] including the actual site you're automating, or a reproducible sample site. Thanks.

@ggorlen See question I changed it.

Thanks, but it's still a bit vague. I suggest showing the actual, full error message (SEO optimization and zero ambiguity for answerers) and a real URL. Is it really all the same word test? I suggest using something like https://www.example.com/bar/baz if you must use a made-up URL.

You might try one of the following:
this.page.waitForUrl("**/*.test.com/test/**");
this.page.waitForUrl("**/www.test.com/test/**");
this.page.waitForUrl(/test\.com\/test\//);

The wildcard * (one path chunk) and ** (many path chunks) parts should be within / and . delimiters. This isn't a regex, it's a glob-style URL pattern.
Here's a runnable, reproducible example:
const playwright = require("playwright"); // ^1.46.1

let browser;
(async () => {
  const url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort";
  browser = await playwright.chromium.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "commit"});
  await page.waitForURL("**/*.wikipedia.org/wiki/**");
  await page.waitForURL("**/en.wikipedia.org/wiki/**");

  // or use a regex:
  await page.waitForURL(/\.wikipedia\.org\/wiki\//);

  // These fail:
  // await page.waitForURL("**/*.wikipedia.org/wiki**");
  // await page.waitForURL("**/.wikipedia.org/wiki/**");
  // await page.waitForURL("**.wikipedia.org/wiki/**");
  // await page.waitForURL("**wikipedia.org/wiki/**");
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

If your page opens in a new tab, capture the tab to a page object, then apply the above on the new page.

@ggorien the url is actually https://community.test.com/t5/test-express/ I tried  await this.page.waitForURL("/community.test.com/"); but that didn't work

That page doesn't load for me. Can you pick a real website that has a similar pattern so I can verify my solution? I think your syntax is markdown, so use backticks to turn it into code so I can see what you tried. "**/*.test.com/t5/**" should work.

From your repost, apparently this opens a new tab. You'll want to capture that, then assert the route on the new tab. But if you shared a [mcve], then there'd be no issues like this.
